# my Cookie value is overwritten by the FormsAuthentication default cookie value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to Create my own forms authentication cookie , because I want to add session ID information in userdata the cookie, but once redirect to home page my cookie value is overwritten by default value.

In login page after validating the username and password.

//Create Form Authentication ticket

```
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2,
                    Login1.UserName,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                    Login1.RememberMeSet,
                    newId,
                    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // add the cookie to user browser
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and i also tried this

```
                HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, true);
                var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
               
                var newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,
                                                              ticket.Name,
                                                              ticket.IssueDate,
                                                              ticket.Expiration,
                                                              true, //persistent 
                                                              newId,
                                                              ticket.CookiePath);

                cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

can any one help on this please

Comment: why don't you use a seperate cookie?

Comment: I want to Validate this cookie in FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate , to check the value of session id is same or different to invalidate the cookie for stolen cookie.